# HTML button tag stuck and won't play HTML5 audio on second click

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-audio

I have a playlist page, which works out fine on the computers. Unfortunately on android, when I click the start button, then the stop button, it's stays orange and does not change the track!

I'm assuming the button tag on android is waiting for something back?

Also, the `src` updating is not working on android.

Here is my javascript:

```js
function Stop ()
{
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.pause();
}

function Start ()
{
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.src = ("new link");
    audie.play();
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```html
<audio id="myAudio" onended="Start()"></audio>

<button type="button" onclick="Start()">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Stop()">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
function Stop ()
{
    audie.muted = true;
}

function Start ()
{
    audie.src = ("new link");
    audie.muted = false;
    audie.currentTime = 0;
}
```

I think `audio.pause` stops the download of a song. Please correct me if I am wrong.